# Automated Server Install Using Live Server Image and autoinstall-editor

Tags: server, system-installation, 20.04

I am trying to follow the current 20.04 Automated Server Install process to create scripted installations for the various Desktops supported by Ubuntu. I was able to follow [the Quick Start Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart)  however this abbreviated document only supports a canned installation script file that uses a fixed user-id and password. The [main documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) refers to a Snap called `autoinstall-editor`.

I have been unable to find this tool which seems to be critical in generating the encrypted password needed for the assigning admin credentials. Can anyone assist me in finding this tool?

Comment: In bold letters above the *autoinstall-editor* paragraph is a notice: "The snap described here does not yet exist"

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out as I missed seeing it however since 20.04 went GA on 4/23 and we are about halfway to 20.10, I was hoping that this might be available somewhere.  If I can figure out the file contents to list the packages I intend to install, I can manually edit the list. The hard part though is converting the encrypted password. If anyone on the team is reading this, an example YAML of selectively installing samba and smbclient would be valuable and I could get around the need for having this utility.

Comment: Do you only need to create a password hash?  `mkpasswd -m sha-512`

Comment: I am having two difficulties. The password hash is one. The second is supplying a valid package list. Initially, I guessed at the package list syntax and got catastrophic parsing error which aborted the install. I found some more detailed control file syntax on the following link. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall I modified my control file input based off my best interpretation and will supply that file in another comment. The result was a complete install with interactive prompting for the user name and password however the package list was not honored.

Comment: The following was the control file input used that did not successfully process the listed packages:   #cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
    snaps:
    - name: go
      channel: 1.14/stable
      classic: true
    debconf-selections: |
    bind9      bind9/run-resolvconf    boolean false
    packages:
    - samba
    - smbclient
    - libreoffice
    - dns-server^
EOF

Comment: FYI. I was able to overcome the parsing error issue of my package list. The gist of the problem was an error message reporting not encountering the EOF indicator to signify the end of the YAML configuration file. What I found was that I had to go into each line of the scripting file that built the YAML file and ensure I had trailing blanks following each line that was expected to be placed in the YAML file. If the line ended in New Line, this could be misconstrued as a continuation of the prior line which would blow the line parser.